# Minecraft execute as armor stand unless other armor stand in distance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

im trying to create a type of conveyor belts for minecraft, therefore im using command like

`execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] if block ~.4 ~-1 ~-.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=south] if block ~-.4 ~-1 ~-.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=south] run tp ~ ~ ~.1`

With this command I'm moving the armorstand (in this case) south, where it gets catched by another commandblock for another direction. Although I want to queue them up, when there is already a armor stand in front. For example when my conveyor belt ends or there is a wall, they should queue up. I thought this could be done by adding the following:

`unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=1]`

As far as I understood this, I thought it'll run the command above, *unless* there is an armor stand in a radius of 1 block. It doesn't seem to work though. Am I missing something or just didn't use the unless part correctly?

Comment: Oh no, I was almost done writing an answer when I noticed that your real problem is just the missing `..`.

Comment: Although this didnt' fix the problem. I think they do stop now with distance=..1, but they seem to count themselves into this, so they dont even move at all.

At least ```execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] at @s unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=..1] if block ~-.4 ~ ~.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=north] if block ~.4 ~ ~.4 minecraft:carved_pumpkin[facing=north] run tp ~ ~ ~-.1``` didnt work

Comment: Of course, because it detects itself. The proper solution is to tag them differently and check for tags. Otherwise you could teleport both anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I got it working without tags or anything, by using
```execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand] at @s unless entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=0.5..1]```

Comment: If you already use such a hacky workaround (which is totally fine in some cases), then you might as well improve it by using `distance=.000001..1`.